# Solving ODE in two mode with the same result in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, simulation, ode

I am using the following commands to solve the ODE function "DynamicFunc":

```
x0_sim = zeros(12,1);
time_sim = [0 100];
options=odeset('AbsTol',1e-9,'RelTol',1e-6);
[tp,xp]=ode45(@DynamicFunc,time_sim,x0_sim,options);
```

The DynamicFunc can be any function and the code works very well.
the time of simulation is 0 - 100 seconds. the finals xp will have a size of 3017x12 (i.e. there are 12 states and 3017 trial points). If I want to run this code inside a FOR loop with duration of 1 second, something like this:

```
x0_sim = zeros(12,1);
time_sim = [0 1];
for tt = 1:100
    options=odeset('AbsTol',1e-9,'RelTol',1e-6);
    [tp,xp]=ode45(@DynamicFunc,time_sim,x0_sim,options);
    x0_sim = xp(:,end);
end
```

The number of final iterations would be so different. How can I make them the same size (for both methods to have the final output with the same vector size)?
I guess the problem can be related to setting an specific option, but I couldn't find any.

Comment: (Sigh)... another example of not using [self-contained code](http://sscce.org/). Why are you iterating every second through your loop, and why are you using specifically ode45 in that case. Also, in the second example, see what happens when you concatenate TP instead of XP, then come back and ask your question.

Comment: I am iterating the simulation because I have to give it a command (input) and find the next state. Using this next state I will calculate a new input for the next iteration. So I cannot run it once. (The XP part was just to show that I am saving the data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems are due to the step-size control in `ODE45` that dynamically increases and decreases the size of the time steps. In your second setup, you enforce the time grid points at every second while in the first setup the algorithm choses its own grid points.

To make both match, you should consider the option of providing a properly chosen timegrid vector `tspan` to get the function values at a predefined grid.

Comment: so what is the solution? using FIXED_SIZE ODE?

Comment: no, better use the `tspan` parameter. I have edited my answer accordingly

Comment: specifically: time_sim = 0:100;

Comment: just try it. maybe you will have to filter out the 'additional' values added by the solver

Comment: What @Jan and @Rasman are saying is that if you specify `tspan` with more than two time points, `ode45` (and the other solvers) will only output solutions at those specific times rather than choosing the output times. The solver is still using an adaptive step-size method, but it uses smart [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) to efficiently output the specified points. So it looks like a fixed step size solver. You can also do this after the fact using the [`deval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deval.html) function.

Comment: Actually you are right changing the time_sim = 0:100, the output will become exactly 101 points. thanks guys.